# Would vector clear or vector swap functions of a .. say parent vector take care of releasing memory used by nested vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, type-definition

Noob question here, I have been working on a game engine for some time now, and now that I want to add funtionality to be able to clean up data and reload it to let's say close and open game levels, I am leaking memory. So my question is about the usage of STL vectors whose elemenst are typedef structures that may include vectors, so, if I want to release the memory consumed by the parent vectory by clearing it, do I need to first clear the elements nested vectors?, Example of one such structure:

```
    typedef struct Particle_Animation{
        unsigned short first_frame;
        unsigned short last_frame;
        unsigned short total_frames;
        unsigned short fastest_period;
    };
    typedef vector<Particle_Animation>Particle_Animations;
    typedef struct ParticlesSubSurf{
        GPU_Rect subsrect;
        GPU_Image *image;
        GPU_Image *normal_image;//normal map of the texture
        Particle_Animations particle_animations;
        unsigned short light_source;
        unsigned short height;
        unsigned short width;
    };
    typedef vector<ParticlesSubSurf> ParticlesSubSVect;
```

If I have a ParticlesSubSVect vector and want to clean it up, do I need to iterate its elements and clean up the elements' vectors of type Particle_Animations.

Thanks much.

Comment: vector doesn't leak memory. It's something you are allocating and not freeing. Run your code in valgrind or similar memory debugger.

Comment: Note: neither clear nor swap will release any memory. The vectors don't shrink unless you call `shrink_to_fit()`. Or it will be freeed when you destroy the vector.

Comment: What are those suspicious `GPU_Image *` pointers? Can they leak? If yes, why `ParticlesSubSurf` doesn't have a destructor that takes care of it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for your comment, those pointers point to sdl_gpu library texture objects, the library includes a GPU_FreeImage() function that takes the pointer as argument to release the sdl_gpu texture object, I have a clean up function to iterate the vectors and release those texture objects. Would a destructor still be needed?

Comment: A destructor makes it impossible to forget the cleanup. You probably want to have a wrapper class that stores a single texture, and use it instead of `GPU_Image *` everywhere. Then only the wrapper needs a custom destructor. In addition to the destructor, you also need a move constructor and a move assignment (I wouldn't write copy operations for this.)

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow thanks for your comment, I have read that vector clear() calls the elements destructors, do I need to define destructors for my typedef for that to work?, or do I not need to worry about those nested vectors at all?, I will try valgrind.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sounds interesting but I have a question, copies of those sdl_gpu pointers are created for every object that uses the texture, so I one of those objects is destroyed would that not break the texture for every other object that used it?

Comment: That depends on how you write it. If you do as I suggested, without copy operations, then it wouldn't let you to make a copy in the first place. You can instead store `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>` though (multiple pointers to a non-copyable class is fine), then the texture will live as long as at least one pointer lives.

Comment: *so, if I want to release the memory consumed by the parent vectory by clearing it* -- The C++ runtime heap manager does not work in the manner you think it does.   If you call `clear()` or even have a vector destroyed, the heap manager marks those positions as "free", and any future allocations will use the free space.  To detect if there is a real memory leak is to call your functions in a loop that creates and destroys your objects.  If you see that the memory usage increases for each iteration, then that is a memory leak.  If you see no increase, then that's the heap manager doing its job.

Comment: Yes, your typedefs will leak like a sieve. But that is not vectors fault.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, I will work on those destructors